# Creating a for loop to subset data on R

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I have a huge set of data that in the .csv format has 2 columns (one Date_time and other is Q.vanda).
This is what the head and tail of the data looks like,

```
    > head(mdf.vanda)
        Date_Time Q.vanda       
    1 1969-12-05 21:00:00       0
    2 1969-12-05 21:01:00       4
    3 1969-12-05 21:05:00      11
    4 1969-12-05 21:20:00      17
    5 1969-12-05 22:45:00      27
    6 1969-12-05 22:55:00      23


    > tail(mdf.vanda)
             Date_Time Q.vanda
    165738 2016-01-19 10:15:00 2995.25
    165739 2016-01-19 10:30:00 2858.04
    165740 2016-01-19 10:45:00 2956.94
    165741 2016-01-19 11:00:00 2972.52
    165742 2016-01-19 11:15:00 2776.99
    165743 2016-01-19 11:30:00 3082.53
```

There are 48 years of data in between and I want to create a for loop to subset them by year (ex. from 1969/10/01 to 1970/10/01, 1970/10/01 to 1971/10/01 etc.)

I wrote a code but, it's giving me an error that I am not able to resolve. I am pretty new at R so, feel free to suggest some other code that you might think is more efficient for my purpose.

code:

```
    cut <- as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character(c('1969/10/01','1970/10/01','1971/10/01','1972/10/01','1973/10/01','1974/10/01','1975/10/01','1976/10/01','1977/10/01','1978/10/01','1979/10/01','1980/10/01','1981/10/01','1982/10/01','1983/10/01','1984/10/01','1985/10/01','1986/10/01','1987/10/01','1988/10/01','1989/10/01','1990/10/01','1991/10/01','1992/10/01','1993/10/01','1994/10/01','1995/10/01','1996/10/01','1997/10/01','1998/10/01',
     '1999/10/01','2000/10/01','2001/10/01','2002/10/01','2003/10/01','2004/10/01',
    '2005/10/01','2006/10/01','2007/10/01','2008/10/01','2009/10/01','2010/10/01',
    '2011/10/01','2012/10/01','2013/10/01','2014/10/01','2015/10/01','2016/10/01')),format = "%Y/%m/%d"))

    df.sub <- as.data.frame(matrix(data=NA,nrow=14496, ncol=96)) #nrow = (31+30+31+31+28)*(4*24)[days * readings/day] , ncol = (48*2)[Seasons*cols]

    i.odd <- seq(1,49, by=2)
    for (i in 1:48) {df.sub[1:length(mdf.vanda$Date_Time[mdf.vanda$Date_Time >= cut[i] & mdf.vanda$Date_Time < cut[i+1]])
    ,i.odd[i]:(i.odd[i]+1)] <- subset(mdf.vanda,mdf.vanda$Date_Time > cut[i] & mdf.vanda$Date_Time < cut[i+1])}
```

Error:

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1:length(mdf.vanda$Date_Time[mdf.vanda$Date_Time >=  : 
  replacement element 1 has 1595 rows, need 1596

Comment: why do you need to subset by group? Do you want an individual data.frame for each group? If no, it is easier to add a factor column with the year, and use dplyr's 'group_by'.

Comment: I need to subset this by groups as I need to perform different functions on each data frame (season) to be able to analyze the data by year.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you want to get?

Comment: This what I want it to look like in a tabular form. I want a sub for each year.
'> print(Sub1314)'
                 'Date_Time Q.vanda'
'149278 2013-12-07 00:00:00    0.00'
'149279 2013-12-07 00:15:00    0.00'
'149280 2013-12-07 00:30:00    0.00'
'149281 2013-12-07 00:45:00    0.00'
'149282 2013-12-07 01:00:00    0.00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a loop here.  Base R has the `cut` function to perform this very operation and significantly faster than the loop.  Since you have the break points defined with your "cut" variable.

```
#cut <- as.POSIXct(c('1969/10/01', ... ,'2016/10/01'),format = "%Y/%m/%d")

mytime<-cut(mdf.vanda$Date_Time, breaks = cut, include.lowest = TRUE)
```

The variable "mytime" is a vector the length of your data frame with a label to bin the data.
You could then use the `split` function to break your dataframe in a list of data frames or use the `group_by` function from the dplyr library for additional data processing.

Answer (score 1):

you can split your data as shown

```
split(mdf.vanda,findInterval(as.Date(mdf.vanda$Date_Time),seq(as.Date("1969-10-01"),as.Date("2016-10-01"),"1 year"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at the convenient `quantmod` package. Once you have Time Series data, you can use the `apply.yearly` function and apply any function to every year of data.

Comment: Quantmod uses the data from already existing websites. How do I get it to retrieve the data from my file (mdf.vanda)?

Comment: Quantmod has functionality to load financial data from some sites but that doesn't prevent you from use other functions like `apply.yearly` on your data. Just load your data the usual way, e.g. reading it from a csv file, and convert it to time series (`xts`) data.

Comment: I.e. `xts(x = mdf.vanda, order.by =mdf.vanda$Date_Time)`